# Making SSRS Report Manager the default website

Tags: iis, reporting-services

I have a server that hosts nothing but reporting services. The default URL for the report manager is myserver/reports

Now, the server is only hosting SSRS and i would like the report manager to have the URL myserver/

How do i do that?

(the server 2012)
Thx
Nicolaj

Comment: Did you take a look at [the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630447.aspx) yet?

Comment: Yes i read the documentation and i searched Google. Might be that i missed something but as far as I can see the documentation tell me how to specify a URL like myserver/reports or the like. I wanted report manager to answer on "myserver" (without the "/reports" part.)